# Daily testing of a rails app on a production server, with automated email responses

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have a rails app on a production server that I Need tested 24 hours for consistency (the tests test various APIs that the app calls).

If a test fails on the server, I need to be informed immediately of this (possibly by email), so that we may fix a problem if it occurs.

We deploy with Capistrano, and use the whenver gem for Cron processing.

CUrrently we are thinking of using whenever to run a shell script in our production directory that runs "rake test", and checks the output of that command with "$?". If the output is non-zero, we invoke sendmail to send an email to me.

I honestly wish there was a more Rubyish way of doing this, but can't come up with any solutions. Any help?

Comment: Would running the test rake task from inside a ruby script be a good solution? You could also capture the output, and if there's an error, it can email you the output.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time looking for the solution of your problem (which is also mine), and ended up with a solution similar to yours.

**Rake task:**

```
namespace :test do

  task :a_test => :environment do
    test_output = `bundle exec rspec spec/lib/a_test`
    if tests_output.include?("Failures:\n")
      MyMailer.alert(test_output).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

**Mailer:**

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def alert(tests_output)
    @tests_output = tests_output
    mail(:subject => '[ALERT] An error has occured')
  end

end
```

**Mailer view (alert.text.erb):**

```
<%= @tests_output.html_safe %>
```